# How to specify a time-out for http.agent?

Tags: clojure

I am working on the following in Clojure:

```
(defn call-soap-function-for-url [url function-name body]
  (http/buffer-bytes 
    (http/http-agent (str url "/soap.php")
                     :connect-timeout 2000
                     :read-timeout 2000
                     :method "POST"
                     :body body
)))
```

The problem is that if the url doesn't exist (for instance), the http-agent blocks the current execution indefinitely, ignoring the timeout I have specified.

What am I please doing wrong?

Thank you for your help - I really appreciate it.

Comment: What HTTP library you are talking about?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using clojure.contrib.http.agent

Comment: Why you aren't specifying :handler function?

Comment: according to the author: "clojure.contrib.http-agent was a weak idea with mediocre execution. (I wrote it.) It is fundamentally flawed in how it deals with exceptions, error-codes, and blocking. Feel free to continue to use it, but I am not supporting it." https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/gA0wivhhiC0 use clj-http or http.async.client